# Writing Generic method for Enum parser

Tags: c#, generics

I have two methods which are doing similar function. I want to merge these two into one so that the code is not repetitive.

First method:

```
private string GetPlanogramStatusListString()
        {
            string outValue = null;
            if (this.POGSelectedStatusList != null)
            {
                outValue = "";
                // Parse the string list to get enum values into a list
                List<string> tempStatusList = new List<string>();
                foreach (object sts in this.POGSelectedStatusList)
                {                    
                    PogStoreData.PlanogramStatusCode enumValue;
                    if (Enum.TryParse<PogStoreData.PlanogramStatusCode>(sts.ToString(), out enumValue))
                    {
                        tempStatusList.Add(((int)enumValue).ToString());
                    }
                }

                outValue = string.Join(",", tempStatusList);
            }
            return outValue;

        }
```

Second method:

```
private string GetMoveStatusListString()
        {
            string outValue = null;
            if (this.POGMovedStatus != null)
            {
                outValue = "";
                // Parse the string list to get enum values into a list
                List<string> tempStatusList = new List<string>();
                foreach (object sts in this.POGMovedStatus)
                {
                    PogStoreData.POGMovedStatus enumValue;
                    if (Enum.TryParse<PogStoreData.POGMovedStatus>(sts.ToString(), out enumValue))
                    {
                        tempStatusList.Add(((int)enumValue).ToString());
                    }
                }

                outValue = string.Join(",", tempStatusList);
            }
            return outValue;

        }
```

I want to merge these two methods to one single method. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add the definition for `POGSelectedStatusList` and `POGMovedStatus` as well as any other supporting types?

Comment: BTW from `foreach(object sts in this.POGSelectedStatusList)` I gather you are using an `ArrayList`. You would be much  better of using `List<PlanogramStatusCode>` which implements `IEnumerable<PlanogramStatusCode>` and you can use `LINQ`.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually compiled and run this code:

```
private string GetEnumListString<T>(IEnumerable list) where T : struct
{
    string outValue = null;
    if (list != null)
    {
        outValue = "";
        // Parse the string list to get enum values into a list
        List<string> tempStatusList = new List<string>();
        foreach (object sts in list)
        {                    
            T enumValue;
            if (Enum.TryParse(sts.ToString(), out enumValue))
            {
                tempStatusList.Add((Convert.ToInt32(enumValue)).ToString());
            }
        }
        outValue = string.Join(",", tempStatusList);
    }
    return outValue;
}

private string GetPlanogramStatusListString()
{
    return GetEnumListString<PogStoreData.PlanogramStatusCode>(this.POGSelectedStatusList);
}

private string GetMoveStatusListString()
{
    return GetEnumListString<PogStoreData.POGMovedStatus>(this.POGMovedStatus);
}
```

It compiles, and produces identical output to the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Since converting a list of objects into a list of integer strings is not tied directly to a class one could use an extension method for this kind of logic. Although the benefit is limited with object types.

Also, what you are doing here is actually Map/Filter/Reduce. That means you could shorten the code slightly and use the standard LINQ names for these operations. (Map/Filter/Reduce translates to .Net Select/Where/Aggregate)

```
        public static string ToIntegers<T>(this IEnumerable<object> values) where T : struct
        {
            return values?.Select(x => {
                T enumValue;
                return Enum.TryParse(x.ToString(), out enumValue) ? Convert.ToInt32(enumValue).ToString() : null;
            })
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + "," + s2);
        }
```

Where LINQ crosses the line between convenient and unreadable is a matter of personal taste. For people used to "Map/Filter/Reduce" this may be very easy to read, for others not so. I just wanted to give some other input since the current answers are very similar.

Comment: This assumes the input may contain items that can't be parsed. If all input is valid, use the single-line suggestion.

Comment: Also note that this code as well as the original question will accept input in two formats - integers as well as enum strings. Not sure if this is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
private string GetsListString<T>(List<object> list)
{
    string outValue = null;
    if (list != null)
    {
        outValue = "";
        // Parse the string list to get enum values into a list
        List<string> tempStatusList = new List<string>();
        foreach (object sts in list)
        {
            T enumValue;
            if (Enum.TryParse<T>(sts.ToString(), out enumValue))
            {
                tempStatusList.Add(((int)enumValue).ToString());
            }
        }

        outValue = string.Join(",", tempStatusList);
    }
    return outValue;
}
```

Comment: This code will not compile - you can't cast T to int. You need to use Convert.ToInt32() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to below code,

```
        private string GetMoveStatusListString<T>(IEnumerable list) where T : struct 
        {
            string outValue = null;
            if (list != null)
            {
                outValue = "";
                // Parse the string list to get enum values into a list
                List<string> tempStatusList = new List<string>();
                foreach (object sts in list)
                {
                    T enumValue;
                    if (Enum.TryParse<T>(sts.ToString(), out enumValue))
                    {
                        tempStatusList.Add(enumValue.ToString());
                    }
                }

                outValue = string.Join(",", tempStatusList);
            }
            return outValue;
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question if the lists that are passed in contain the enum type.  In fact since they go through the trouble of parsing the `ToString` of them to the enum type I would hope that they don't.  So `IEnumerable` would be a better argument type than `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: The original code compiles a comma-separated list of numbers based on the parsed values. This code would create a comma-separated list of the enum value names as strings instead, so would not be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

A single line of code would suffice:

```
string GetStatusList(IEnumerable<object> array) 
{
    return string.Join(",", array.Select((e)=>(Convert.ToInt32(e)).ToString()) );
}
```

to be used as

```
// GetPlanogramStatusListString();
var x=GetStatusList(POGSelectedStatusList.ToArray());
// 1,2,2

// GetMoveStatusListString();
var y=GetStatusList(POGMovedStatus.ToArray());
// 2,3,2,1,2
```